# append a textarea input type with a string on ng-click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am having an issue with using an ng-click to append data to a textarea input field.  I am trying to implement a dropdown menu that adds boilerplate data to a textarea but I want to be able to select multiple boilerplate data to the textarea.

here is what I have for html:

```
<div id="specialinstructions-group" class="form-group">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <label data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Special Flash Instructions<b class="caret"></b></label>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-click="addSpecialInstructions('Please unplug the system for 10 seconds after the BIOS and EC update completes.')"><span>10 Second Powercycle</span></li>
      </ul>
    <textarea name="FlashInstructions" class="form-control" id="FlashInstructions" rows="3" ng-model="formData.flashinstructions">        </textarea>
</div>
```

Here is my controller/function I am trying to use to append:

```
formApp.controller('formController', function($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.formData.flashinstructions = "";
    $scope.addspecialInstructions = function(text) {
            var added = $scope.formData.flashinstructions + text;
            $scope.formData.flashinstructions = added;
            alert(added);
        }
```

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: formData is not defined
```

I know JQuery has a .append() function but I cannot seem to get that to work.

I am pretty new to Javascript, JQuery and AngularJS. I could be dealing with a scope issue and would like to know where to look next for a solution.

Any help you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: I only have 1 <li> tag above from a list of many <li> entries, for brevity

Comment: Typo: rename your controller method to `$scope.addSpecialInstructions` and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your controller like this.

```
formApp.controller('formController', function($scope) {
    var formData = {};
    formData.flashinstructions = "";
    formData.addspecialInstructions = function (text) {
        var added = formData.flashinstructions + text;
        formData.flashinstructions = added;
        alert(added);
    }
    $scope.formData = formData;
```

You html looks like

```
<div id="specialinstructions-group" class="form-group">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <label data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Special Flash Instructions<b class="caret"></b></label>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-click="formData.addSpecialInstructions('Please unplug the system for 10 seconds after the BIOS and EC update completes.')"><span>10 Second Powercycle</span></li>
      </ul>
    <textarea name="FlashInstructions" class="form-control" id="FlashInstructions" rows="3" ng-model="formData.flashinstructions">        </textarea>
</div>
```

I also encourage to you to use object literal in controller, not everything bind with $scope. So first create an object and at the end of your controller , you can bind it $scope. Its good practice.

Comment: Thank you Kashif. That fixed the solution.  the $scope binds have been giving me trouble quite frequently. your help is fabulous1